# My async function not work in python 3.8.13

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-3.8

```
import asyncio

async def_1():
    pass
async def_2(number):
    
    for i in range(number):
        globals['example_{}'.format(i)] = def_1()
asyncio.run(def_2)
```

My work file is .ipynb and python3.8.13 and use visual basic studio.
my code's structure is that. I want to work as ASynchronous function, but code didn't work.
so I want to know what I do to work this code.

Comment: start with ```async def func_1():``` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

Comment: And after that you need to use `asyncio.run(def_2())`.